# Why $\Bbb Z$ = (integers) is an integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

Is there a proof for $\Bbb Z$ being an integral domain? Or is it an axiom that if $a*b=0$ then $a=0$ or $b=0$ where $a$, $b$ belong to $\Bbb Z$. Is it so obvious?

Comment: That depends on how you define $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: If the definition of$*$ is ordinary it is obvius

Comment: I believe the usual term is "integral domain".

Comment: Must have been a translation issue, as domain and region are similar in common English.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just prove that if $a,b\ne0$, then $ab\ne0$. Which is quite obvious, because for positive $b$ you have
$$a\cdot b=\underbrace{a+\ldots+a}_{b\text{ times}}\ne0$$
Because it's either $\geq a$ or $\leq a$ depending on the sign of $a$.

For $b<0$ just consider $(-a)(-b)$.

Comment: Yes you are right !Didnt though of it!

Answer (score 1):

If you can use that $\mathbb Z \subset \mathbb Q$ then it is clear because every subring of a field is an integral domain.

Comment: unfortunately this uses some circular logic, because I think a typical construction of the rationals uses the fact that Z is an integral domain